# How to reset time back to 0 in pygame?

Tags: python-2.7, timer, pygame, reset

I am trying to make a game in pygame where you need to click the image to gain a score.My program works but i still need to fix 2 bugs:

## Bug 1

When the user presses 'c' that is play again,the **time does not reset back to 0. I want it back to 0 , so that every 10 seconds the game gets over and you cant play it anymore.

## Bug 2

The time starts even if the user does not press 'c' , i.e to play game.So by the time user reads the rules (assuming they took 5 seconds to read rules) , and then they press 'c' they only have 5 more seconds to play.I want it to do it so that only when the user presses 'c' the game time starts.

This is my game run up source code:

```
def runGame():
    #Initial score is 0
    score=0
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    while not gameExit:
        while gameOver == True:
            #Game Over message

            gameDisplay.fill(black)
            message_to_screen("Game over",
                              red,
                              y_displace=-50,
                              size="large")
            message_to_screen("Press C to play again or Q to quit.",
                              white,
                              y_displace=50,
                              size="medium")
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c: #If user press 'c' , game starts
                        gameLoop()
        gameDisplay.fill((white))

        #Possible Error from here
        # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        #My time function    
        time=pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000
        if time==11: #Checks if time hit 10 (i took as 11 as it should complete the 10th second)
            global time
            global score
            score=0
            time=0
            gameOver=True
        #~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Till here
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                running=False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
                # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
                x, y = event.pos
                if foodrect.collidepoint(x, y):
                    foodrect.center=(random.randint(5,1060),random.randint(5,700))
                    print "New Position: ",foodrect.center
                    score+=1
                    continue

        gameDisplay.blit(foodimg,foodrect)
        showtime=font.render("Time: "+str(time),0,(0,0,0))
        gameDisplay.blit(showtime,(950,10))
        scoredisplay(score)
        pygame.display.update()
```

## My Game Loop

```
def gameLoop():
    clock.tick(FPS)
    runGame()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
gameLoop()
```

## Full Code

As requested by  Herman Yanush.

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()

foodimg=pygame.image.load("food.png")
foodrect=foodimg.get_rect()

#Colours
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

LEFT =1



#Game Display
display_width = 1080
display_height  = 720
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Click It! ~ Snapnel Productions')
gameDisplay.fill((white))

font=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",30)


#Clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 30

cellSize=10

#Font Size
exsmallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 17)
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 80)

#The score function - displays the score on top right
def scoredisplay(scoredef=0):
    text=smallfont.render("Score :%s" %(scoredef) ,True ,white)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,[0,0])
def scoredisplay1(musicname):
    text=exsmallfont.render("Now Playing :%s" %(musicname) ,True ,white)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,[690,5])    
#Starting Of the game
def game_intro():

    intro = True
    while intro:    
      for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_c:
                intro = False
            if event.key ==pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        #Game Initial display message
        message_to_screen("Click It!",
                          red,
                          -200,
                          size="large")
        message_to_screen("This Game is created by Shrapnel",
                          white,
                          -30,
                          size="small")
        message_to_screen(" the food to gain a point!",
                          white,
                          10,
                          size="small")
        message_to_screen("Press 'C' to play the game or 'Q' to quit.",
                          white,
                          150,
                          size="small")
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
#Text Size
def text_objects(text,color, size):
    if size=="small":
        textSurface=smallfont.render(text, True ,color)
    elif size=="medium":
        textSurface=medfont.render(text, True ,color)
    elif size=="large":
        textSurface=largefont.render(text, True ,color)


    return textSurface,textSurface.get_rect()

#Message to screen
def message_to_screen(msg,color,y_displace=0,size="small"):
    textSurf,textRect=text_objects(msg,color,size)
    textRect.center = (display_width / 2),(display_height / 2)+y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf,textRect)

#Score Display
def scoredisplay(scoredef=0):
    text=smallfont.render("Score :%s" %(scoredef) ,True ,black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,[0,0])

score=0
global a
a=10

#print score
def runGame():
    score=0
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 7
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    while not gameExit:
        deadZones=[]
        while gameOver == True:
            #Game Over message

            gameDisplay.fill(black)
            message_to_screen("Game over",
                              red,
                              y_displace=-50,
                              size="large")
            message_to_screen("Press C to play again or Q to quit.",
                              white,
                              y_displace=50,
                              size="medium")
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()
        gameDisplay.fill((white))

        time=pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000
        if time==11:
            global time
            global score
            score=0
            time=0
            gameOver=True
        #print score

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                running=False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
                # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
                x, y = event.pos
                if foodrect.collidepoint(x, y):
                    foodrect.center=(random.randint(5,1060),random.randint(5,700))
                    print "New Position: ",foodrect.center
                    score+=1
                    continue

        gameDisplay.blit(foodimg,foodrect)
        showtime=font.render("Time: "+str(time),0,(0,0,0))
        gameDisplay.blit(showtime,(950,10))
        #scoredisplay(score)
        pygame.display.update()
def gameLoop():
    clock.tick(FPS)
    runGame()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
game_intro()
gameLoop()
```

Thanks in advance to help.

Comment: Is the bottom half the gameloop() part?  I can't see it otherwise.

Comment: @marienbad Yes it is.I added it now.

Comment: Can you give the full code?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have a solution that at least I use. While sometimes it is nice to use pygame.time.get_ticks, there is an easier solution. Before your while loop set a variable called frame to 0. Then at the end of your while loop type:

```
if gameEnd == True:
    frame=0
    score=0
else:
    frame+=1
```

Then all you have to do is only draw the picture when frame>0. You can also easily manipulate frame. Message me if you need any more help.

Comment: Is it possible for you to write this into my code and give me the solution?